# Can anyone explain how the statements are being executed once recursion is over?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
void ReversePrint(Node *head)
{
    Node *sec=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    sec->next=NULL;
    sec->data=0;
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        ReversePrint(head->next);
        Node *tmp=sec;
        tmp->data=head->data;
        cout<<tmp->data<<endl;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
cout<<"hello"<<endl;
}
```

input: 2 1 4 5

output is:-
hello
5
hello
4
hello
1
hello
2
hello

I dont understand how hello is printed before the last element (first element in this case, i.e. reverse order) of the linked list.

Comment: Mentioning the programming language would help.

Comment: @Juhana I have mentioned the programming language now, thanks for suggestion

Comment: I suggest following this code with a debugger to understand the execution flow. Also notice that this code is leaking memory.

Answer (score 2):

tmp and sec are unneeded, and just cause a memory leak every time.
Remove them and use instead:

```
cout << head->data << endl;
```

So:

```
void ReversePrint(Node *node)
{
    //cout << "(";
    if (node != NULL)
    {
        ReversePrint(head->next);
        cout << node->data << endl;
    }
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    //cout << "hello" << ")" << endl;
}
```

What was done serves no purposes, it looks like an attempt to reverse the list itself, but that should have been done differently, without allocation.

Comment: output for this function is same as that of given in question

Comment: `((((((((hello) 5) hello) 4) hello) 1) hello) 2) hello` - That is the first hello is printed when node is null (and the if statement is skipped).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you call `ReversePrint()` with "head = 2" -> "next = 1" -> "next = 4" -> "next = 5" -> "next = NULL". Only then comes the first `cout`, printing <kbd>hello</kbd>. Then the program retraces the call stack (going back to node "5"), printing <kbd>5</kbd> followed by <kbd>hello</kbd>. Then retracing again (going back to node "4")... etc.

If you want to avoid that first "hello" (and taking into account the other answers), try this:

```
void ReversePrint( Node * node )
{
    if( node == NULL )  // to make sure the very first element of the list is not NULL
        return;

    if( node->next != NULL )
        ReversePrint( node->next );

    cout << node->data << endl;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```